# What is wrong with my ContentProvider in Android 4.3?

Tags: java, android, uri

My app works just fine with any Android version before `4.3`. I mean when I input a word into `edWord` (EditText field), a list of similarly-spelled words will appear in the list view.

But in `Android 4.3`, it always returns `null`, claiming that app_ContentProvider cannot find the supported `uri`.

I use the following code to show the word list:

```
public void showWordlist() {    

    edWord.setEnabled(true);
    String word = edWord.getText().toString();      
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://doyle.app_name.app_ContentProvider/dict/" + mDBFile.fileName + "/list/" + word);
    edWord.requestFocus();

    try
    {
        Cursor result = getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);    
        Log.i(MAIN_TAG, "Found word = " + result); 
        //I think the problem lies somewhere here because 
        //the 'result' is always 'null' (see the above log.i)

        if (result != null)
        {
            int countRow=result.getCount();
            Log.i(MAIN_TAG, "countRow = " + countRow);
            mLSTCurrentWord.clear();
            //mLSTCurrentContent.clear();
            mLSTCurrentWordId.clear();
            mAdapter.clear();
            if (countRow >= 1)
            {
                int indexWordColumn = result.getColumnIndex("word");
                int indexIdColumn = result.getColumnIndex("id");                
                result.moveToFirst();
                String strWord;
                int intId;
                int i = 0;
                do
                {                       
                    strWord = Utility.decodeContent(result.getString(indexWordColumn));
                    intId = result.getInt(indexIdColumn);                       
                    mLSTCurrentWord.add(i,strWord);
                    mLSTCurrentWordId.add(i,intId);
                    //mLSTCurrentContent.add(i,strContent);
                    mAdapter.add(strWord);
                    i++;
                } while (result.moveToNext()); 
            }

            result.close();
        }

        lstWord.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(MAIN_TAG, "Error = " + ex.toString());  
    }
    edWord.setEnabled(true);        
}
```

And here is my [app_ContentProvider](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15034088/Others/Temps/AppProvider.java).

I have no idea whether there are any changes in `Android 4.3` that stop my app from functioning normally.

Regarding my code lines above, can you please tell me what the problem might be? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try set the property android:exported="true" for your content provider in your Manifest. It seems that the default value of this property has changed in android 4.3